# I am unable to burn DVDs. I have attempted to remedy this issue, but nothing seems to work

Tags: dvd, brasero, k3b

Weirdly enough, I WAS able to burn data to DVDs, as a matter of fact I just burned 2, but then it just stopped working.

I tried using Brasero, Xfburn and K3b, and they all give some sort of error. I tried installing/uninstalling the software, removing/re-adding wodim, but to no avail.

I am fairly new to Ubuntu, and the terminal still scares me a bit, sorry for bothering you with this issue. **Thank you for your time and effort, it is greatly appreciated. Happy Holidays!**

---

> Xfburn: Failure: Cannot reserve track of 4458938368 bytes

---

> > Brasero log:

```
 Checking session consistency (brasero_burn_check_session_consistency brasero-burn.c:1739)
BraseroBurnURI called brasero_job_get_action
BraseroBurnURI called brasero_job_get_action
BraseroBurnURI called brasero_job_set_output_size_for_current_track
BraseroBurnURI stopping
BraseroBurnURI called brasero_job_get_action
BraseroBurnURI called brasero_job_get_session_output_size
BraseroBurnURI called brasero_job_get_action
BraseroBurnURI called brasero_job_get_current_track
BraseroBurnURI no burn:// URI found
BraseroBurnURI stopping
BraseroLocalTrack called brasero_job_get_action
BraseroLocalTrack called brasero_job_get_action
BraseroLocalTrack called brasero_job_set_output_size_for_current_track
BraseroLocalTrack stopping
BraseroLocalTrack called brasero_job_get_action
BraseroLocalTrack called brasero_job_get_session_output_size
BraseroLocalTrack called brasero_job_get_action
BraseroLocalTrack called brasero_job_get_current_track
BraseroLocalTrack no remote URIs
BraseroLocalTrack stopping
BraseroLibburn called brasero_job_get_action
BraseroLibburn creating input
BraseroLibburn called brasero_job_get_action
BraseroLibburn unsupported operation
BraseroLibburn deactivating
BraseroLibisofs called brasero_job_get_action
BraseroLibisofs called brasero_job_get_action
BraseroLibisofs called brasero_job_set_current_action
BraseroLibisofs creating volume
BraseroLibisofs called brasero_job_get_data_label
BraseroLibisofs called brasero_job_get_flags
BraseroLibisofs called brasero_job_get_current_track
BraseroLibisofs Adding graft disc path = /TANGLED.avi, URI = file:///home/oana/Videos/TANGLED.avi
BraseroLibisofs Found parent
BraseroLibisofs Adding graft disc path = /Dumbo-1941.mkv, URI = file:///home/oana/Videos/classic%20disney%20movies%201/DUMBO/Dumbo-1941.mkv
BraseroLibisofs Found parent
BraseroLibisofs Adding graft disc path = /Jurassic.Park[1993]DvDrip-aXXo.avi, URI = file:///home/oana/Videos/Jurassic.Park.Trilogy.Pack%5B2007%5DDvDrip-aXXo/Jurassic.Park%5B1993%5DDvDrip-aXXo.avi
BraseroLibisofs Found parent
BraseroLibisofs Adding graft disc path = /Mulan-Disney.1998.DVD-Rip.XviD.avi, URI = file:///home/oana/Videos/Mulan-Disney.1998.DVD-Rip.XviD.avi
BraseroLibisofs Found parent
BraseroLibisofs Adding graft disc path = /Jurassic.Park.III[2001]DvDrip-aXXo.avi, URI = file:///home/oana/Videos/Jurassic.Park.Trilogy.Pack%5B2007%5DDvDrip-aXXo/Jurassic.Park.III%5B2001%5DDvDrip-aXXo.avi
BraseroLibisofs Found parent
BraseroLibisofs Adding graft disc path = /The.Lost.World-Jurassic.Park[1997]DvDrip-aXXo.avi, URI = file:///home/oana/Videos/Jurassic.Park.Trilogy.Pack%5B2007%5DDvDrip-aXXo/The.Lost.World-Jurassic.Park%5B1997%5DDvDrip-aXXo.avi
BraseroLibisofs Found parent
BraseroLibisofs called brasero_job_set_output_size_for_current_track
BraseroLibisofs called brasero_job_get_action
BraseroLibisofs Finished track successfully
BraseroLibisofs stopping
BraseroLibburn called brasero_job_get_action
BraseroLibburn creating input
BraseroLibburn called brasero_job_get_action
BraseroLibburn called brasero_job_get_device
BraseroLibburn Drive (/dev/sr0) init result = 1
BraseroLibburn called brasero_job_get_flags
BraseroLibburn called brasero_job_get_media
BraseroLibburn called brasero_job_get_fd_in
BraseroLibburn called brasero_job_get_fd_in
BraseroLibburn called brasero_job_get_input_type
BraseroLibburn called brasero_job_get_session_output_size
BraseroLibburn Setting multi 0
BraseroLibburn Setting burnproof 0
BraseroLibburn Setting dummy 0
BraseroLibburn called brasero_job_get_session_output_size
BraseroLibburn called brasero_job_set_current_action
BraseroLibisofs called brasero_job_get_action
BraseroLibisofs linked to BraseroLibburn
BraseroLibisofs called brasero_job_get_action
BraseroLibisofs Entering thread
BraseroLibisofs called brasero_job_get_fd_out
BraseroLibisofs called brasero_job_set_nonblocking
BraseroLibisofs called brasero_job_get_fd_in
BraseroLibisofs called brasero_job_get_fd_out
BraseroLibisofs called brasero_job_set_current_action
BraseroLibisofs called brasero_job_get_fd_out
BraseroLibisofs Writing to pipe
BraseroLibburn burn_drive_convert_fs_adr( /dev/sr0 )
BraseroLibburn Writing
BraseroLibburn called brasero_job_set_dangerous
BraseroLibburn called brasero_job_set_current_action
BraseroLibburn called brasero_job_get_session_output_size
BraseroLibburn called brasero_job_set_current_action
BraseroLibburn burn_drive_is_enumerable_adr( /dev/sr0 ) is true
BraseroLibburn called brasero_job_get_session_output_size
BraseroLibburn called brasero_job_set_current_action
BraseroLibburn Async START UNIT succeeded after 0.1 seconds
BraseroLibburn called brasero_job_get_session_output_size
BraseroLibburn called brasero_job_set_current_action
BraseroLibburn mmc_set_streaming: end_lba=2295103 ,  r=4584 ,  w=11080
BraseroLibburn called brasero_job_get_session_output_size
BraseroLibburn called brasero_job_set_current_action
BraseroLibburn Allocating buffer via mmap()
BraseroLibburn called brasero_job_get_session_output_size
BraseroLibburn called brasero_job_set_current_action
BraseroLibburn dvd/bd Profile= 1Bh , obs= 32768 , obs_pad= 1
BraseroLibburn called brasero_job_get_session_output_size
BraseroLibburn called brasero_job_set_current_action
BraseroLibburn DVD+R pre-track 01 : get_nwa(0), ret= 1 , d->nwa= 0
BraseroLibburn called brasero_job_get_session_output_size
BraseroLibburn called brasero_job_set_current_action
BraseroLibburn called brasero_job_get_session_output_size
BraseroLibburn called brasero_job_set_current_action
BraseroLibburn called brasero_job_get_session_output_size
BraseroLibburn called brasero_job_set_current_action
BraseroLibburn called brasero_job_get_session_output_size
BraseroLibburn called brasero_job_set_current_action
BraseroLibburn called brasero_job_get_session_output_size
BraseroLibburn called brasero_job_set_current_action
BraseroLibburn called brasero_job_get_session_output_size
BraseroLibburn called brasero_job_set_current_action
BraseroLibburn called brasero_job_get_session_output_size
BraseroLibburn called brasero_job_set_current_action
BraseroLibburn called brasero_job_get_session_output_size
BraseroLibburn called brasero_job_set_current_action
BraseroLibburn called brasero_job_get_session_output_size
BraseroLibburn called brasero_job_set_current_action
BraseroLibburn called brasero_job_get_session_output_size
BraseroLibburn called brasero_job_set_current_action
BraseroLibburn called brasero_job_get_session_output_size
BraseroLibburn called brasero_job_set_current_action
BraseroLibburn called brasero_job_get_session_output_size
BraseroLibburn called brasero_job_set_current_action
BraseroLibburn called brasero_job_get_session_output_size
BraseroLibburn called brasero_job_set_current_action
BraseroLibburn called brasero_job_get_session_output_size
BraseroLibburn called brasero_job_set_current_action
BraseroLibburn called brasero_job_get_session_output_size
BraseroLibburn called brasero_job_set_current_action
BraseroLibburn called brasero_job_get_session_output_size
BraseroLibburn called brasero_job_set_current_action
BraseroLibburn called brasero_job_get_session_output_size
BraseroLibburn called brasero_job_set_current_action
BraseroLibburn called brasero_job_get_session_output_size
BraseroLibburn called brasero_job_set_current_action
BraseroLibburn called brasero_job_get_session_output_size
BraseroLibburn called brasero_job_set_current_action
BraseroLibburn called brasero_job_get_session_output_size
BraseroLibburn called brasero_job_set_current_action
BraseroLibburn called brasero_job_get_session_output_size
BraseroLibburn called brasero_job_set_current_action
BraseroLibburn SCSI error condition on command 2Ah WRITE(10): [3 0C 00] Write error
BraseroLibburn Something went wrong
BraseroLibburn called brasero_job_error
BraseroLibburn finished with an error
BraseroLibburn asked to stop because of an error
    error       = 15
    message = "An error occurred while writing to disc"
BraseroLibisofs stopping
BraseroLibisofs Getting out thread
BraseroLibisofs disconnecting BraseroLibisofs from BraseroLibburn
BraseroLibburn stopping
BraseroLibburn closing connection for BraseroLibburn
Session error : An error occurred while writing to disc (brasero_burn_record brasero-burn.c:2856)
```

---

> > > K3b debugging output:

```
Devices
-----------------------
HL-DT-ST DVDRAM GSA-T40N JR03 (/dev/sr0, CD-R, CD-RW, CD-ROM, DVD-ROM, DVD-R, DVD-RW, DVD-R DL, DVD+R, DVD+RW, DVD+R DL) [DVD-ROM, DVD-R Sequential, DVD-R Dual Layer Sequential, DVD-R Dual Layer Jump, DVD-RAM, DVD-RW Restricted Overwrite, DVD-RW Sequential, DVD+RW, DVD+R, DVD+R Dual Layer, CD-ROM, CD-R, CD-RW] [SAO, TAO, RAW, SAO/R96P, SAO/R96R, RAW/R16, RAW/R96P, RAW/R96R, Restricted Overwrite, Layer Jump] [%7]

K3b::IsoImager
-----------------------
mkisofs print size result: 2274496 (4658167808 bytes)

System
-----------------------
K3b Version: 2.0.2
KDE Version: 4.7.2 (4.7.2)
QT Version:  4.7.4
Kernel:      3.0.0-14-generic

Used versions
-----------------------
mkisofs: 1.1.11
cdrecord: 1.1.11

cdrecord
-----------------------
/usr/bin/wodim: Operation not permitted. Warning: Cannot raise RLIMIT_MEMLOCK limits.
scsidev: '/dev/sr0'
devname: '/dev/sr0'
scsibus: -2 target: -2 lun: -2
Linux sg driver version: 3.5.27
Wodim version: 1.1.11
SCSI buffer size: 64512
Beginning DMA speed test. Set CDR_NODMATEST environment variable if device
communication breaks or freezes immediately after that.
TOC Type: 1 = CD-ROM
Driveropts: 'burnfree'
Device type    : Removable CD-ROM
Version        : 5
Response Format: 2
Capabilities   : 
Vendor_info    : 'HL-DT-ST'
Identification : 'DVDRAM GSA-T40N '
Revision       : 'JR03'
Device seems to be: Generic mmc2 DVD-R/DVD-RW.
Current: 0x001B (DVD+R)
Profile: 0x0012 (DVD-RAM) 
Profile: 0x0011 (DVD-R sequential recording) 
Profile: 0x0015 (DVD-R/DL sequential recording) 
Profile: 0x0016 (DVD-R/DL layer jump recording) 
Profile: 0x0014 (DVD-RW sequential recording) 
Profile: 0x0013 (DVD-RW restricted overwrite) 
Profile: 0x001A (DVD+RW) 
Profile: 0x001B (DVD+R) (current)
Profile: 0x002B (DVD+R/DL) 
Profile: 0x0010 (DVD-ROM) 
Profile: 0x0009 (CD-R) 
Profile: 0x000A (CD-RW) 
Profile: 0x0008 (CD-ROM) 
Profile: 0x0002 (Removable disk) 
Using generic SCSI-3/mmc DVD-R(W) driver (mmc_mdvd).
Driver flags   : SWABAUDIO BURNFREE 
Supported modes: PACKET SAO
Drive buf size : 1114112 = 1088 KB
Drive DMA Speed: 12699 kB/s 72x CD 9x DVD
FIFO size      : 12582912 = 12288 KB
Speed set to 11080 KB/s
Track 01: data  4442 MB        
Total size:     5101 MB (505:26.61) = 2274496 sectors
Lout start:     5102 MB (505:28/46) = 2274496 sectors
Current Secsize: 2048
HINT: use dvd+rw-mediainfo from dvd+rw-tools for information extraction.
Blocks total: 2274496 Blocks current: 2274496 Blocks remaining: 0
Starting to write CD/DVD at speed   8.0 in real SAO mode for single session.
Last chance to quit, starting real write in    2 seconds.
   1 seconds.
   0 seconds. Operation starts.
Waiting for reader process to fill input buffer ... Errno: 5 (Input/output error), reserve track scsi sendcmd: no error
CDB:  53 00 00 00 00 00 22 B4 C0 00
status: 0x2 (CHECK CONDITION)
Sense Bytes: 70 00 05 00 00 00 00 0A 53 35 1E 0E 72 05 00 00
Sense Key: 0x5 Illegal Request, Segment 0
Sense Code: 0x72 Qual 0x05 (no more track reservations allowed) Fru 0x0
Sense flags: Blk 0 (not valid) 
cmd finished after 0.005s timeout 200s
/usr/bin/wodim: Cannot open new session.
input buffer ready.
Writing  time:    0.068s
/usr/bin/wodim: fifo had 192 puts and 0 gets.
/usr/bin/wodim: fifo was 0 times empty and 0 times full, min fill was 100%.

cdrecord command:
-----------------------
/usr/bin/wodim -v gracetime=2 dev=/dev/sr0 speed=8 -sao driveropts=burnfree -data -tsize=2274496s -

mkisofs
-----------------------
2274496
I: -input-charset not specified, using utf-8 (detected in locale settings)
  0.02% done, estimate finish Sun Dec 25 02:56:44 2011
  0.04% done, estimate finish Sun Dec 25 00:32:17 2011
  0.07% done, estimate finish Sat Dec 24 23:42:56 2011
  0.09% done, estimate finish Sat Dec 24 23:18:01 2011
  0.11% done, estimate finish Sat Dec 24 23:02:36 2011
  0.13% done, estimate finish Sat Dec 24 22:52:40 2011
  0.15% done, estimate finish Sat Dec 24 22:56:21 2011
  0.18% done, estimate finish Sat Dec 24 22:49:39 2011
  0.20% done, estimate finish Sat Dec 24 22:44:17 2011
  0.22% done, estimate finish Sat Dec 24 22:40:08 2011
  0.24% done, estimate finish Sat Dec 24 22:36:44 2011
  0.26% done, estimate finish Sat Dec 24 22:33:53 2011

mkisofs calculate size command:
-----------------------
/usr/bin/genisoimage -gui -graft-points -print-size -quiet -volid Cannibal Holocaust -volset  -appid K3B THE CD KREATOR (C) 1998-2010 SEBASTIAN TRUEG AND MICHAL MALEK -publisher  -preparer  -sysid LINUX -volset-size 1 -volset-seqno 1 -sort /tmp/kde-administrator/k3bg12767.tmp -rational-rock -hide-list /tmp/kde-administrator/k3bp12767.tmp -joliet -joliet-long -hide-joliet-list /tmp/kde-administrator/k3bm12767.tmp -no-cache-inodes -full-iso9660-filenames -iso-level 3 -path-list /tmp/kde-administrator/k3bX12767.tmp

mkisofs command:
-----------------------
/usr/bin/genisoimage -gui -graft-points -volid Cannibal Holocaust -volset  -appid K3B THE CD KREATOR (C) 1998-2010 SEBASTIAN TRUEG AND MICHAL MALEK -publisher  -preparer  -sysid LINUX -volset-size 1 -volset-seqno 1 -sort /tmp/kde-administrator/k3bm12767.tmp -rational-rock -hide-list /tmp/kde-administrator/k3bw12767.tmp -joliet -joliet-long -hide-joliet-list /tmp/kde-administrator/k3bK12767.tmp -no-cache-inodes -full-iso9660-filenames -iso-level 3 -path-list /tmp/kde-administrator/k3bY12767.tmp
```

Comment: looks like you found it... or someone did :-D

Comment: Can you restart your machine, and try again? Seems to be an issue with the buffers.

Answer (score 2):

Researching a bit on Ubuntu Forums led me to [this thread](http://ubuntuforums.org/archive/index.php/t-1895338.html). The line of error that's at the beginning of your charts is [actually a bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/cdrkit/+bug/149076/). But at the end of the thread you can also see from the posts that the cause of the failures was infact a faulty medium. Also at the very end it is suggested you try doing so by disabling the `md5` plugin. So you might give it a shot as well.

Answer (score 0):

it could be the back-end used which is cdrkit, you can read more about it [here](http://cdrtools.sourceforge.net/private/cdrecord.html)

you could replace it with a [ppa](https://launchpad.net/~brandonsnider/+archive/ubuntu/cdrtools)

Comment: You posted the same answer [elsewhere](https://askubuntu.com/a/1028327/250300). You should rather vote/flag to close as duplicate, or, if the question is not a duplicate, tailor the answer to this specific question. Note that posting the same link in many answers can be considered spamming.

Comment: yes it's kind of general information which most people are unaware of