# Brasero makes unusable DVD's

Tags: dvd, burning, brasero

Brasero is fond of writing .md5 CRC files on the DVD.  Most DVD players are allergic to 
stray files and refuse to play DVD's with .md5 files written on them

Why on earth does Brasero do this and how can it be stopped.

Oh, while we are here, I tried Brasero's video writer, but it refused to write a directory and demanded a single file.  The DVD source I have, uses a VIDEO_TS directory.  This is a common industry standard.

Comment: Have you tried K3b?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! It is preferred if you can post separate questions instead of combining your questions into one. That way, it helps the people answering your question and also others hunting for atleast one of your questions. Thanks! And don't use Askubuntu for reporting bugs.

Comment: Please don't create multiple questions about the same topic. Stick to one and edit that to provide more information as needed.

Answer (score 0):

Just disable the "Image Checksum" plugin if you don't want Brasero to write the .md5 file on the disc.

For the DVD-Video, I've never tried this but you could make an ISO using genisoimage and then burn it.

genisoimage -dvd-video -udf -o iso_file.iso folder

Where "folder" is the folder containing the VIDEO_TS/AUDIO_TS directories and iso_file.iso is the ISO that you will burn.
As I said I've never tried this before, so try this ISO file first using VLC. If VLC loads the ISO correctly you should burn it without problems.

Answer (score 0):

As for creating a video DVD (or ISO):

[K9Copy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K9Copy) is a powerful tool that can read a VIDEO_TS directory structure (or a DVD) and either extract the video files or create a video DVD (depending on what output mode you've selected).

To install [K9Copy on Ubuntu](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/K9Copy), you need to enable the multiverse repository, either by changing the config file or by using the Software Sources gui. Other distributions like Fedora have it in their default repository.

Answer (score 0):

it could be the back-end it uses which probably is cdrkit, you can read more about it [here](http://cdrtools.sourceforge.net/private/cdrecord.html)

you could replace cdrkit with a [ppa](https://launchpad.net/~brandonsnider/+archive/ubuntu/cdrtools)

Comment: You posted the same answer [elsewhere](https://askubuntu.com/a/1028329/250300). You should rather vote/flag to close as duplicate, or, if the question is not a duplicate, tailor the answer to this specific question. Note that posting the same link in many answers can be considered spamming.

Comment: how else would you spread awareness or should people continue to waste their cds

Comment: maybe i should have used the comment button, i forgot i can add a comment now